# Are type arguments in interfaces an actual type?

Tags: java, generics, kotlin

Don't think the title is best wording for this question, I have an interface with two type arguments, and I seem to be able to cast `this` as both of the types at the same time, see reproducable example:

```
interface BaseResult<S : BaseResult<S, E>, E : BaseResult<S, E>> {

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    fun isSuccess(): Boolean {
        return try {
            val a = this as S //ClassCastException expected
            val b = this as E
            println(a) //com.BaseResultTest$ExampleResult$Error@17d10166
            println(b) //com.BaseResultTest$ExampleResult$Error@17d10166
            true
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            false
        }
    }
}
```

Test:

```
class BaseResultTest {

    sealed class ExampleResult: BaseResult<ExampleResult.Success, ExampleResult.Error> {
        object Success: ExampleResult()
        object Error: ExampleResult()
    }

    @Test
    fun test() {
        val error = ExampleResult.Error
        assertEquals(error.isSuccess(), false)
    }
}
```

Am I missing something, or is this a bug in the language? Using v1.3.61

Comment: Why is this tagged java?

Answer (score 1):

It is [type erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens), which works the same way for all generics, not just for interfaces. In this case both casts become equivalent to `as BaseResult<*, *>`.

Kotlin has [a way to avoid it](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters), but only for type parameters of `inline` methods, not classes or interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't so much of a bug in the Language, but more of a logic error of the writer. While you can inflect the type of `S` and `E`, they're still similar to an `Option` and it's sub types of `Some` and `None` (Some is always typed to the `Option<_>` whereas `None` always is empty.

Part of your problem here is that you *cannot guarantee* the subclass is a type of `S` or `E` without explicitly declaring the subtypes for those cases. You can see examples of this in trying to [implement `Either`](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/implementing-kotlin-either/8730), and some other examples [including this one about Either](https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture-Kotlin/blob/2f1aa7d7f32fd0c5f4732132879c2f6cd577ad06/app/src/main/kotlin/com/fernandocejas/sample/core/functional/Either.kt#L19).

I hope this helps answer the question.